# MySQL mariaDB union select execution ignorance

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

there are two tables in one structured query as below

```
SELECT "field" 

UNION SELECT "<category_id>" 
UNION SELECT category_id FROM categories
UNION SELECT "</category_id>"

UNION SELECT "<inventory_id>"
UNION SELECT inventory_id FROM inventories
UNION SELECT "</inventory_id>"

UNION SELECT "<inventory_name>"
UNION SELECT inventory_name FROM inventories
UNION SELECT "</inventory_name>"

UNION SELECT "<category_name>" 
UNION SELECT category_name FROM categories
UNION SELECT "</category_name>"
```

query result:

| field |
| --- |
| field |
| category_id |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| category_id |
| inventory_id |
| inventory_id |
| inventory_name |
| inv1 |
| inv2 |
| inv3 |
| inventory_name |
| category_name |
| cate1 |
| cate2 |
| cate3 |
| category_name |

`<inventory_id></inventory_id>` should contain 1 which is the inventories.inventory_id record

**notice**
when i moved  `<inventory_id></inventory_id>` to `<category_id></category_id>` in query

i have got the expected result in `<inventory_id></inventory_id>` but `<category_id></category_id>` is empty

tables structure for simulation

```
create table inventories(inventory_id int AUTO_INCREMENT, inventory_name varchar(255), PRIMARY key (inventory_id));
create table categories(category_id int AUTO_INCREMENT, category_name varchar(255), PRIMARY key (category_id));
INSERT INTO categories(category_name) VALUES("cate1"),("cate2"),("cate3");
INSERT INTO inventories(inventory_name) VALUES("inv1"),("inv2"),("inv3");
```

use top select query to get the result

i have using https://sqliteonline.com/ to simulate it with phpmyadmin and got the same result

Comment: Do you really want `field` in the query results, or should it be the name of the column?

Comment: Where do `main` and `Uncategories` come from in your output? The example category names are `cate1`, `cate2`, and `cate3`.

Comment: Where are the `<`, `/`, and `>` in your results?

Comment: @Barmar The missing angle brackets are likely just hidden by browser. I'd be more worried about the order of the results changing, since SQL will **not guarantee** the records come back in the order listed. It may _seem_ to come back that way, but then you move this to a production server and suddenly the `SELECT` from one of the tables is delayed to take advantage of an existing index walk.

Comment: Is this supposed to be generating XML? If so, shouldn't each item be wrapped in its own tag, not a tag around each list?

Comment: Like `<categories><category><category_id>1</category_id><category_name>cate1</category_name><category><category><category_id>2</category_id><category_name>cate2</category_name><category>`

Comment: 1) field is column and i use it as a key in my code.
 
2) 'main' and uncategories' are records in my localhost so you can replace them by 'inv1' and 'cate1'

3) i can't use '</> ' in my question text because i display my result in table

5) it's like XML tags but i wrap outputs between the tags without writing it in XML way

Comment: If `field` should be the column name, use that as an alias in the first query instead of as data to be selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `UNION ALL`. By default, `UNION` removes duplicates, and some of the `category_id` and `inventory_id` values are the same.

Comment: Moreover, UNION DISTINCT may rearrange rows - even when no one row was removed.

Comment: Indeed, when I test the query at sqliteonline.com or sqlfiddle.com, the results are sorted lexicographically. There's also a `NULL` row that I can't explain.

Comment: it work when i used union all before union removes duplicates values. but if you could tell my which case it return null rows.

Comment: I got the null row with your original query.